# Both if and else statements running JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When i press 1 to go to "Start" it runs start BUT it also runs "instructions".
So after it says "Welcoe22222" it would say "HAHAHAH" right after it but i only want the "start" function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


alert("Welcome to the BattleShip Game!!!")
name = prompt("What is your name: ")
alert("Welcome "+name)
option = prompt("1. Start Game \n \n 2. Instructions \n \n Select: ")
if (option ==1)
    start()
else (option ==2)
    instructions()

function start() {

    alert("Welcoe22222")

}

function instructions() {

    alert("HAHAHAH")

}

</script>
```

Comment: This is why you should use semicolons, at least until you fully understand JS syntax.

Comment: @SLaks I hate semicolons, but perhaps you mean brackets?

Comment: @Saiid: No; I mean semicolons (although braces would also help).  You can't rely on ASI until you fully understand how JS syntax works.

Comment: The semicolons aren't the problem, though. If they had used the brackets in the if/else, it wouldn't be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `if`

```
else if (option == 2)
//   ^^
```

Better to use [block statement `{ /* ... */ }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), like

```
if (option == 1) {
    start();
} else if (option == 2) {
    instructions();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `else` syntax is completely wrong.

If you want `else if`, you need to write that.

Your code is parsed using automatic semicolon insertion as

```
if (option ==1)
    start()
else
    (option ==2);
instructions()
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think for not getting confusing, or making your teammates confused about your code, it is better to use block statement (I mean if you think in the future you may want to add more lines of codes in the if statement.

You can't have parentheses after `else. if you say`else (x==y)`, you will get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

---

It should be:

```
if (option == 1) {
    start();
} else if (option == 2) {
    instructions()
}
```